# How to deploy single Android project to both Froyo and Honeycomb from IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to develop a hybrid app for both 3.2 and 2.2/2.3 using IntelliJ Community Edition. But when I want to deploy the app (minSDK is set to 8 in the manifest) to a phone it doesn't work. It acts like no supported devices are connected to the computer. The project's build target is set to 3.2 in order to be able to access the Honeycomb support in IntelliJ.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'd love to have a single project that makes a hybrid app and deploys to both devices (2.2/2.3 and 3.2).

Answer (score 0):

You may have [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-68064). Check the link for the workaround. If the issue remains, please provide your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: The problem consisted of the phone not having the drivers installed. Whoops :P